# SoftwareSerial clear buffer?

Tags: arduino

My software serial(Arduino Uno pins 5/6) is never clears the incoming buffer data.
So , if i send some data to the serial ,and later i would like to read the incoming data, i get all the previous data i have sent+ the new incoming data.
Why is it not clearing my previous sent data ?

```
while(wifiSerial.available()) 
        {
          wifiChar  = wifiSerial.read();
          wifiContent.concat(wifiChar);
          delay(10);                  
        }
        Serial.println("abc:");
       Serial.println(wifiContent); //gets all the data i have sent+the new received
```

Answer (score 0):

that is because you are using the ATE (echo return)
in this case it will return the command that you send and the request data.